How to limit myself from writing more than 2 characters in a node's body field?
In Drupal 10.3.10 with CKEditor 5, I have a core content type named "Article" and a node that contains a "Body" field which is a CKEditor multiline text field.
This text field is a <div> that contains the CSS class ck-editor__editable.
How to alert myself immediately after two characters have been added to that field?
It doesn't matter what kind of characters were added to that text field or in what way the characters were added to that text field (keyboard only, mouse only, etc.) so the main thing that matters is the character amount in that text field.
Notes

I actually want to limit the node to much more than two characters, more like a 10,000 characters but just for the sake of simplicity I ask about limiting it to two.
I fail to target input events in that editable div with JavaScript in various ways but anyway I am not even sure that JavaScript is the correct way to go here.


Google: drupal ckeditor character limit

One way to do this is the Maxlength module, which has the advantage of working with the field regardless of whether or not CKEditor is enabled.
The CKEditor Wordcount module might appear to do what you want but actually does not:

While this will prevent entry on the client side, you should not rely
on this as any sort of field validation. This will also have no effect
on non-CKEditor based fields.


Just looking at the code of  Maxlength, it doesn't either enforce the validation server-side. So I'd say, if it is a requirement, either modules are valid for the front-end and a custom constraint will be needed for the server-side validation.
